# jqgrid getRowData ignores columnChooser

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using the latest free jqGrid (pulled today). I'm using columnChooser. By default I load all available columns to the grid. I use columnChooser to remove a few columns. This works great.

I use getRowData() to export the grid data. This works great, even maintaining my filters and sorting. But getRowData always returns all the columns, even when I remove them using columnChooser.

How can I make getRowData include just the columns visible in the grid? I've tried reload, and remapColumns without success.

```
$('#iown').jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#iownpager', { caption: "", buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator", onClickButton: function () {
    $('#iown').jqGrid('columnChooser',{modal: true, width: 550,
        done : function(perm) {
            if (perm) {
                $('#iown').jqGrid("remapColumns", perm, true);
            }
        }
    });
},
title: "Choose columns"
});


$("#iown").jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#iownpager', { caption: '', buttonicon: 'ui-icon-disk', onClickButton: function () {
    var gridData = jQuery("#iown").getRowData();
    var postData = JSON.stringify(gridData);

    JSONToCSVConvertor(postData, report, true);
},
title: 'Download Current Grid View',
id: 'iown-dl'
});
```

Thank you,
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to me independent from `columnChooser`. You use just `getRowData` which return the data from **all columns, inclusive hidden columns, of the current page**.

I suggest you to replace usage of `getRowData` to the following code

```js
var iCol, $grid = $("#iown"), colModel = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"),
    idPrefix = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "idPrefix"), tr, td, cm, cmName, item,
    nCols = colModel.length, rows = $grid[0].rows, iRow, nRows = rows.length, data = [];

for (iRow = 0; iRow < nRows; iRow++) {
    tr = rows[iRow];
    if ($(tr).hasClass("jqgrow")) {
        item = {}; // item of returned data
        for (iCol = 0; iCol < nCols; iCol++) {
            cm = colModel[iCol];
            cmName = cm.name;
            if (!cm.hidden && cmName !== "cb" && cmName !== "subgrid" && cmName !== "rn" && cm.formatter !== "actions") {
                td = tr.cells[iCol];
                try {
                    item[cmName] = $.unformat.call($grid[0], td, { rowId: tr.id, colModel: cm }, iCol);
                } catch (exception) {
                    item[cmName] = $.jgrid.htmlDecode($(td).html());
                }
            }
        }
        item.id = $.jgrid.stripPref(idPrefix, tr.id);
        data.push(item);
    }
}
```

The code fills `data` array with the data from the grid and works very close to `getRowData` method. I added only additional test for `hidden` property of the column, which you need, removed some code required for TreeGrid only and added setting of `id` property.

Comment: Thank you Oleg! I made one small change. I removed this line:

Comment: I removed this line: item.id = $.jgrid.stripPref(idPrefix, tr.id); because it was returning my first column (the ID) at the end of each row. But I can see the value in having it in some situations. Maybe getRowData can be made to accept parameters {hidden: false, id: false} ??

Comment: @Mike: Thanks for the idea! I think I will implement such options in my fork of jqGrid. [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid)

Comment: @Mike: I included the feature in the main code of free jqGrid on GitHub. See [the commit](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/cb2816c4d1a4aac2bfc909258c78744cc98a43c3).

Comment: This is great Oleg. I was thinking about this feature and thought that id: true should override hidden: false for the id only. For many of my implementations the id is hidden because it serves as a key for server side database updates, and might be useful for dynamic charting. But if it's hidden it would not be available. Does this make sense? You have have thought about this already. I read your commit note but I wasn't sure. Either way I'll download and test drive. Thank very much, Mike

Comment: @Mike: You are welcome! I implemented the behavior where `includeId: true`  option **force** export of rowid. The name of the property will be either the name of the column which have `key: true` which is not hidden or or the name of `prmNames.id` property. I don't recommend you to use any hidden columns with id property. Instead of that one cal use `id` property of `prmNames` option. For example you can use `prmNames: { id: "userId"}` instead of the usage hidden column with the `name: "userId"`. Rowid will be saved in `id` property of `<td>` and one don't need additional hidden `<td>` column.

Comment: Works great. My call to getRowData now looks like this: `var gridData = jQuery("#iown").getRowData({skipHidden: true, includeId: false});`

Comment: Oleg, I am investigating the use of your new feature `var filteredData = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "lastSelectedData")` because it seems to get data for all pages, with sorting and filtering, where getRowData only gets the current page. My grid can go more that a single page, and even with rowNum set to 20,000!. Can the the new changes to you've made to getRowData for hidden columns be applied to `var filteredData = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "lastSelectedData")` ??

Comment: @Mike: I am in vocation for two weeks and can't help you now. You can get the filteredData and remove unneeded proporties